# With PostgreSQL, how does one express a table constraint that two time ranges do not overlap where some other condition holds?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to add constraints to a PostgreSQL (using 11.5 version) table to ensure that no overlapping timezone-aware ranges exist for an another entity identified by foreign key.

I started be creating a table for experimentation and inserting two rows where the tstzranges overlapped, expecting the second row insert to fail.

This is my table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE demo (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    duration tstzrange,
    EXCLUDE USING GIST (
        id WITH =,
        duration WITH &&
    )
);
```

These are my two inserts:

```
INSERT INTO demo (duration) VALUES
    ('(2019-08-29 09:00:00, 2019-08-29 15:00:00)'),
    ('(2019-08-29 10:00:00, 2019-08-29 14:00:00)');
```

I expected the second row insert to fail, as it is contained within the duration of the first row.  However, both rows are created.

```
1   ["2019-08-29 09:00:00+00","2019-08-29 15:00:00+00")
2   ["2019-08-29 10:00:00+00","2019-08-29 14:00:00+00")
```

Does anyone have any pointers on what I'm doing wrong, and the best way to properly accomplish checking if two ranges overlap for an entity?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your exclusion constraint specifies two fields, one of which is also the primary key. as such, this constraint would never be violated.

fixing the table definition such to will prevent overlapping ranges from being inserted.

```
create table demo (
  id int primary key generated by default as identity,
  duration tstzrange,
  exclude using gist (duration with &&)
);
```

also, since you mention you are on postgresql version 11.5, you should really be moving away from `serial` and use `generated by default as identity` instead for your auto increment primary key column.

if you specify the exclusion constraint on another (non-unique) field (with equality) & the duration field (with overlap), then the database will reject rows if the duration overlaps with another duration for the entity.

example (note that for this code to work, the btree_gist extension needs to be enabled):

```
create table demo (
  id int primary key generated by default as identity,
  room_no int,
  duration tstzrange,
  exclude using gist (room_no with =, duration with &&)
);
insert into demo (room_no, duration) values
(1, '(2019-08-29 10:00:00, 2019-08-29 14:00:00)');
insert into demo (room_no, duration) values
(1, '(2019-08-29 09:00:00, 2019-08-29 15:00:00)');
```

you get the following nice error message:

```
ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "demo_room_no_duration_excl"
DETAIL:  Key (room_no, duration)=(1, ("2019-08-29 09:00:00+00","2019-08-29 15:00:00+00")) conflicts with existing key (room_no, duration)=(1, ("2019-08-29 10:00:00+00","2019-08-29 14:00:00+00")).
```